# What's the word for aggregating by two attributes together, rather than separately?

Tags: statistics, data, data-analysis

Let's imagine we have this underlying data:

```
pet_name,pet_type,age,city
Goldie,fish,2,New York
Slippy,fish,2,New York
Jasper,cat,10,New York
Moppet,cat,3,London
Omar,cat,London
Holly,cat,7,London
Leo,cat,8,London
```

And let's imagine we are making counts based on this dataset, and we want a single file with columns for type and city, with cells containing counts:

```
pet_type,city,count
fish,New York,2
cat,New York,1
cat,London,4
```

I know how to write the code to do this, but what I don't know is to specify this *verbally* in ordinary speech, if I was making a request to a data analysis team.

If I say "please can I have statistics broken down by pet type and city", I tend to be given two separate files which contain less information than what I need (a file of the count by type, and a file of the count by city).

The best I can do is "statistics broken down by both pet type and city, together", but that's not actually clear at all, and again I tend to end up with separate files.

I feel there must be a commonly understood technical description for what I want. Is there?

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer or, alternatively, please describe why you consider it not correct or what is not clear in it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want it exactly, I think the terms you are looking for may either by "[contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table)" or "[pivot table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table)".